# How to run multiple tor browser 5.0.2 how it is different 4.5?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, protocol, network-configuration

how to run multiple tor browser 5.0.2
Pleace help me thak you for ancwer

Comment: please give a link to this question I can not find

Comment: The TOR browser version 5 on all other steels

Comment: In TOR browser version 5